# Is it important to go out and drink/party/ have dinner / visit powerful colleagues?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, tech-industry

I was in Amazon Seattle  US and moved from department of same firm. I was told by tenured employees that in order to switch teams internally, one should keep the plan a secret

Later I came to know that every manager has a fixed firing quota/stack ranking and they fire employees who are unable to hide their plan about switching team.

Why did my mentors and tenured employees not inform me about this firing quota earlier when I asked them? How should a new employee know?

Is it important to go out and drink/party/ have dinner / visit powerful colleagues?

Comment: Gods only know what Amazon's corporate culture is, or whether any of this is true, or whether any of it actually applies in your case. Headcount reductions happen, and are sometimes performance based -- or sometimes claimed to be performance based. Socializing is generally irrelevant; being a good person to work with is highly relevant.

Comment: There's so many red flags in this question. The way you jump around between topics, the lack of a coherent question, the lack of evidence for any ownership of your own actions. I obviously don't know what happened (nor does anyone else, hence the downvotes), but my hunch is that when your manager said you were fired for 'poor performance' it was because of your poor performance.

Comment: @quant from his question it sounds like Amazon has decided to emulate GE's successful corporate culture.

Answer (score 3):

> Why did my mentors and tenured employees not inform me about this
> firing quota earlier when I asked them?

"Stacked ranking".

Stacked ranking pits every employee against every other on a relative value scale. Your co-workers have every incentive to make you look less valuable so that you will get axed instead of them. Naturally they are not going to offer you any effective advice about how to protect yourself from them.

Comment: Most of life, even in a ranked-revjew workplace, is positive sum.